# Can clone conda (without admin), but cannot activate it

Tags: python, environment, conda

I am using Anaconda in a server. The environment default is c:\anaconda.
I have no admin privilege, so I cannot apply 'conda install gdal'.
The program suggests cloning the environment.

I have cloned it.
When I type

```
conda env list
```

My environment is shwon correctly.
However, when I

```
deactivate
```

And try to

```
activate mine
```

Conda says there is no such environment...

Anybody?
Thanks.

Comment: The actual message is: 'No environment named "mine" exists in C:\Anaconda\envs'. Maybe if I could inform C:\anaconda\envs that there is another envs folder in another location...?

Comment: I'm not really sure if conda is meant to work if you have limited privileges.

Comment: Still unable to do anything. @EdisonGustavoMuenz, should I just give up?

Comment: I wasn't able to clone. But I used a *.bat file to set PATH and then open PyCharm. It worked!